# Refactor method to add commas to a string of numbers

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I was working on a method to add commas to a number that is passed. I.E. separate_commas(1000) would return "1,000" or separate_commas(100000) would return "100,000"...etc.

Now that I've solved it, I'm wondering how I could refactor without regular expressions. Would appreciate suggestions, thank you in advance. Ruby 2.1.1p76

```
def separate_comma(x)
  x=x.to_s
  len=-4
  until len.abs > x.length
    x.insert(len, ',')
    len-=4
  end
  return x
end
```

Comment: You might look at how Rails implements its `number_with_delimiter` method: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8607577fc8f2d5767d9fc8001b3985fa541aa557/activesupport/lib/active_support/number_helper/number_to_delimited_converter.rb

Comment: I haven't worked with Rails, just using Ruby right now.

Comment: What is your goal of refactoring this? E.g. have you thought about how you support internationalization in your app, and what should this function do (should it adapt to locale)

Comment: @CarySwoveland Actually, the question is not an exact duplicate. The linked question has a different delimiter (but the essence is the same). Beware of that. Your answer is good for this question but not for the linked one. But it's not only you.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed it with `def separate(n,c=' ')...`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, I am not supposed to solve this one with Regular Expressions which the one you linked to is doing.

Comment: You have a point, but note that three of the answers to the previous question did not use a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly pretty, but it is a little more ruby-esque

```
num.to_s.reverse
        .split('').each_slice(3).to_a
        .map{|num| num.reverse.join('')}.reverse.join(',')
```

Comment: That's pretty close to @Yardboy's earlier answer, though some of the operations are in a different order (e.g., `num.reverse.to_s`). You don't need `to_a`, btw.